# How can i delete documents on firestore?

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need your help. I need your advice for about firestore delete document. I have been working for 2 days this find codes. But everyone told it theoretically. As a last resort, I wanted to write here. How can i get position value ? And how can i delete documents on firestore ? Thank you so much for now your replies...

**GorevRecyclerAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.oztekapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GorevRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GorevRecyclerAdapter.PostHolder> {


private ArrayList <String> adliyeList;
private ArrayList <String> gorevbaslikList;
private ArrayList <String> gorevkonuList;
private ArrayList <String> gorevsaatilist;
private ArrayList <String> gorevtarihiList;
private ArrayList <String> useremailList;

public GorevRecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<String> adliyeList, ArrayList<String> gorevbaslikList, ArrayList<String> gorevkonuList, ArrayList<String> gorevsaatilist, ArrayList<String> gorevtarihiList, ArrayList<String> useremailList) {
    this.adliyeList = adliyeList;
    this.gorevbaslikList = gorevbaslikList;
    this.gorevkonuList = gorevkonuList;
    this.gorevsaatilist = gorevsaatilist;
    this.gorevtarihiList = gorevtarihiList;
    this.useremailList = useremailList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public PostHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_row,parent,false);

    return new PostHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PostHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.useremail.setText(useremailList.get(position));
    holder.adliye.setText(adliyeList.get(position));
    holder.gorevbaslik.setText(gorevbaslikList.get(position));
    holder.gorevkonusu.setText(gorevkonuList.get(position));
    holder.gorevtarihi.setText(gorevtarihiList.get(position));
    holder.gorevsaati.setText(gorevsaatilist.get(position));

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return useremailList.size();
}

class PostHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView adliye, gorevkonusu, gorevbaslik, gorevsaati, gorevtarihi, useremail;

    public PostHolder(@NonNull final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        adliye = itemView.findViewById(R.id.adliyeTextView);
        gorevbaslik = itemView.findViewById(R.id.gorevBaslikTextView);
        gorevkonusu = itemView.findViewById(R.id.gorevKonuTextView);
        gorevtarihi = itemView.findViewById(R.id.gorevTarihTextView);
        gorevsaati = itemView.findViewById(R.id.gorevSaatTextView);
        useremail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.userEmailTextView);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent (itemView.getContext(), GorevDetayActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("gorevbaslik", gorevbaslikList.get(getAdapterPosition()));
                intent.putExtra("gorevkonu", gorevkonuList.get(getAdapterPosition()));
                intent.putExtra("gorevtarihi", gorevtarihiList.get(getAdapterPosition()));
                intent.putExtra("gorevsaati", gorevsaatilist.get(getAdapterPosition()));
                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

    }
}

public void deleteItem(int position){
    getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getReference().delete();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

and **GorevDetayActivity.java**

```
package com.example.oztekapp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GorevDetayActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText gorevbaslik,gorevkonu,gorevsaat,gorevtarih;
private Button guncelle;
private Spinner adliye;
private ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;
private AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog;
private FirebaseFirestore firestore;
private ArrayList<String> adliyeList;
private ArrayList <String> gorevbaslikList;
private ArrayList <String> gorevkonuList;
private ArrayList <String> gorevsaatilist;
private ArrayList <String> gorevtarihiList;
private ArrayList <String> useremailList;
private GorevRecyclerAdapter gorevRecyclerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gorev_detay);

    gorevbaslik = findViewById(R.id.detaygorevbaslik);
    gorevkonu = findViewById(R.id.detaygorevkonusu);
    gorevtarih = findViewById(R.id.detaytarih);
    gorevsaat = findViewById(R.id.detaysaat);
    adliye = findViewById(R.id.detayadliye);
    firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    gorevRecyclerAdapter = new GorevRecyclerAdapter(adliyeList,gorevbaslikList,gorevkonuList,gorevsaatilist,gorevtarihiList,useremailList);


    Intent i = getIntent();
    String gorevbasligi = i.getStringExtra("gorevbaslik");
    String gorevkonusu = i.getStringExtra("gorevkonu");
    String gorevtarihi = i.getStringExtra("gorevtarihi");
    String gorevsaati = i.getStringExtra("gorevsaati");

    gorevbaslik.setText(gorevbasligi);
    gorevkonu.setText(gorevkonusu);
    gorevtarih.setText(gorevtarihi);
    gorevsaat.setText(gorevsaati);
    arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.adliyeler,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    adliye.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menudetay,menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull final MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.gorevsil)
    {
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(GorevDetayActivity.this);
        alertDialog.setTitle("Görev Sil");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Görevi silmek istediğinize emin misiniz ?");
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Evet", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                firestore.collection("Görevler").document().delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(GorevDetayActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                        Toast.makeText(GorevDetayActivity.this, e.getLocalizedMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                });



            }
        }).setNegativeButton("Vazgeç", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                dialog.dismiss();

            }
        });

        alertDialog.create().show();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Comment: At first glance this looks fine `getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getReference().delete();`, but of course it's impossible to say more without seeing what `getSnapshots()` does (so how you **read** the data).

Comment: Where do you get getspnapshots ? I don't  understand

Comment: getsnapshots is at end of the first snippet, (though you should know what's inside the code you posted). Separately, it's really difficult to be of any help with the code posted as it's coupled with android things and your customized abstractions. I would suggest to post a [Minimum Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with only the Firestore interactions as well as the error messages you're getting. Welcome to StackOverflow btw!

Comment: thank u so much bro :)